# What does the L icon mean in Microsoft Word?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, microsoft-word-2010, microsoft-office-2010

For as long as I've used Microsoft Word 2010 (it probably also exists in later versions), whenever selecting an item in a list a black L-like icon appears in the document's ruler:

[image]

Adjusting this icon doesn't seem to actually do anything for me in my current document, and neither does anything happen when I get rid of it by selecting it and dragging down.

What exactly is this icon and what's it for?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That L indicates the Left tab stops. [Tab stops](https://edu.gcfglobal.org/en/word2013/indents-and-tabs/1/) include:

> ### Types of tab stops include:
>
> **Left Tab**: Left-aligns the text at the tab stop
>
> **Center Tab**: Centers the text around the tab stop
>
> **Right Tab**: Right-aligns the text at the tab stop
>
> **Decimal Tab**: Aligns decimal numbers using the decimal point
>
> **Bar Tab**: Draws a vertical line on the document
>
> **First Line Indent**: Inserts the indent marker on the ruler and indents the first line of text in         a paragraph
>
> **Hanging Intent**: Inserts the hanging indent marker,and indents all lines other than the first         line

Comment: This appears to be the answer except that weirdly, for me, moving the L tab doesn't actually seem to change anything. Maybe this is a bug in my copy of Word 2010.

Comment: @Prometheus You can also try to moved it by double-clicking on it(make sure sure that "Left tab" tooltip is shown), then changing the parameter shown on the Tabs window. Or press it also when the tooltip is shown then move it. Or you can click on Paragraph section of the Home ribbon, then "Line and Page Breaks" tab, then click on Tabs button.

Comment: Moving the tab stop does nothing unless someone pressed the tab key to insert a tab character. Moving the indent or the first-line indent, on the other hand, will have immediate effect on the paragraph that is the focus. Here are references to my page on basic formatting: http://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/basic_formatting.htm#Tabs, http://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/basic_formatting.htm#Indents

Answer (score 1):

[Word Tabs](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/using-the-ruler-in-word-775014ca-7bb9-4b75-ba19-4478c4a836d1)

> Tabs are a paragraph-formatting feature used to align text. When you press the Tab key, Word inserts a tab character and moves the insertion point to the tab setting, called the tab stop. You can set custom tabs or use Word’s default tab settings. -[Source](https://www.mediacollege.com/microsoft/word/tabs.html#:~:text=Tabs%20are%20a%20paragraph%2Dformatting,setting%2C%20called%20the%20tab%20stop.&text=Tabs%20are%20set%20to%20distribute,are%20set%20every%20half%2Dinch.)